# How can I tell (in a generator expression) which language a target is compiled as?

Tags: cmake, buildconfiguration, generator-expression

I want to use a generator expression which puts some text on the command-line of compiling certain targets of mine. The thing is, I need different text for CUDA targets and different text for C++ targets; and for reasons, I have to use the same generator expression for all of them.

So, I want write something like `$<IF:$<TARGET_LANGUAGE:CUDA>,foo,bar>` - except there is no such thing as `TARGET_LANGUAGE`.

[Here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#target-dependent-expressions) is the list of target-dependent generator expression kinds; I've reproduced it below. I don't see something I could use for the language. What can I do?

```
TARGET_EXISTS
TARGET_NAME_IF_EXISTS
TARGET_NAME
TARGET_PROPERTY
TARGET_OBJECTS
TARGET_POLICY
TARGET_FILE
TARGET_FILE_BASE_NAME
TARGET_FILE_PREFIX
TARGET_FILE_SUFFIX
TARGET_FILE_NAME
TARGET_FILE_DIR
TARGET_IMPORT_FILE
TARGET_IMPORT_FILE_BASE_NAME
TARGET_IMPORT_FILE_PREFIX
TARGET_IMPORT_FILE_SUFFIX
TARGET_IMPORT_FILE_NAME
TARGET_IMPORT_FILE_DIR
TARGET_LINKER_FILE
TARGET_LINKER_FILE_BASE_NAME
TARGET_LINKER_FILE_PREFIX
TARGET_LINKER_FILE_SUFFIX
TARGET_LINKER_FILE_NAME
TARGET_LINKER_FILE_DIR
TARGET_LINKER_LIBRARY_FILE
TARGET_LINKER_LIBRARY_FILE_BASE_NAME
TARGET_LINKER_LIBRARY_FILE_PREFIX
TARGET_LINKER_LIBRARY_FILE_SUFFIX
TARGET_LINKER_LIBRARY_FILE_NAME
TARGET_LINKER_LIBRARY_FILE_DIR
TARGET_LINKER_IMPORT_FILE
TARGET_LINKER_IMPORT_FILE_BASE_NAME
TARGET_LINKER_IMPORT_FILE_PREFIX
TARGET_LINKER_IMPORT_FILE_SUFFIX
TARGET_LINKER_IMPORT_FILE_NAME
TARGET_LINKER_IMPORT_FILE_DIR
TARGET_SONAME_FILE
TARGET_SONAME_FILE_NAME
TARGET_SONAME_FILE_DIR
TARGET_SONAME_IMPORT_FILE
TARGET_SONAME_IMPORT_FILE_NAME
TARGET_SONAME_IMPORT_FILE_DIR
TARGET_PDB_FILE
TARGET_PDB_FILE_BASE_NAME
TARGET_PDB_FILE_NAME
TARGET_PDB_FILE_DIR
TARGET_BUNDLE_DIR
TARGET_BUNDLE_DIR_NAME
TARGET_BUNDLE_CONTENT_DIR
TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS
TARGET_RUNTIME_DLL_DIRS
```

Comment: You are probably looking for [LINKER_LANGUAGE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LINKER_LANGUAGE.html) property, which could be requested using `$<TARGET_PROPERTY>` generator expression. Note, that there is `$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE>` expression which corresponds to the single **source file**. It extracts [LANGAUGE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/LANGUAGE.html) property of that file.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: Hmm... I'm not sure if the LINKER_LANGUAGE really needs to be the same as the COMPILE_LANGUAGE. e.g. with C and C++, or CUDA and C++ for example.

Comment: Yes, as far as I understand CUDA, CUDA won't be used for linking. But this just explains that your request "language a target is compiled as" is simply wrong: It is not the **target** which is compiled with C/C++/CUDA. It is a **source file** which is compiled with such language. And since a *target* may consist from the several *source files*, there is **no such notion** like "compile language for a target". You, probably, want to express your needs in other terms.